# Oracle APEX - display SQL table in a particular way

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am making a user profile page and the user (currently logged in) data is stored in USERS table.
I created a user profile page and I have been changing the type of the Region, but none of them are what I'm looking for.

I want to display the user information like this:

[image]

This user information is fetched from SQL table, so I tried all Reports but table view is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a region type of "Classic Report", there is a report template called "Value Attribute Pairs - column". Here is an example (query source `select * from emp where ename = 'KING'` ):

[image: builder]

output looks like this.

[image: report]

Needs a bit of massaging - if you want headers like in the sample you showed then maybe 3 different report regions but you get the point.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try region type "Static content" with Collapsible template for each section like User Profile.